# Performing 'document.execCommand' on 'delete' keyevents - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keyevent

I have created [this demo plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/j6xTuNritm9KwonlO8Du?p=preview) to replicate the issue.

I want to apply `strikeThrough`command whenever a delete operation is performed. For example:

**If user selects "Text" and press `delete` or `backspace` , it should become <strike>Test</strike>. It shouldn't get deleted.
Can someone help me on**

```
$container.bind('keydown keyup', function (e) {
    console.log(e)
    if(e.keyCode===8 || e.keyCode===46){
        $document[0].execCommand('strikeThrough', false); // line 1
        e.preventDefault();  // line 2
    }
});
```

I can capture the events as below but `line 1` and `line 2` doesn't work together. So how stop `delete` event and apply `execCommand` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did bind "twice".

It is not "don't work", it is "work twice".

Fix code as following:

```
$container.bind('keyup', function (e) {
    console.log(e)
    if(e.keyCode===8 || e.keyCode===46){
        $document[0].execCommand('strikeThrough', false); // line 1
        e.preventDefault();  // line 2
    }
});
$container.bind('keydown', function (e) {
    console.log(e)
    if(e.keyCode===8 || e.keyCode===46){
        e.preventDefault();  // line 2
    }
});
```